# How do I use if condition when setting the routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<div id="stage">
    <div class="space-item"
       *ngFor="let space of spaces; let i=index; trackBy:trackBySpaces"
       routerLink="/space/{{space.space_id}}"
       [ngStyle]="spaceStyles(positions[i].x, positions[i].y)"
    >
        {{space.space_id}}|{{space.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

In the code above, how could I do NOT set the routerLink attribute when the space.space_id is empty, I wish to have something like this.

```
if(space.space_id){routerLink="/space/{{space.space_id}}"}
```

but I cann't find any solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be used in template:

```
[routerLink]="space.space_id ? '/space/' + space.space_id : 'defaultUrl'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like I should read the doc more carefully.